Npgsql reference JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute
Trying to upgrade Npgsql from version 6, to version 8.
During runtime I got:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute' from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
How to fix it and why do your reference JetBrains?
